# Cannot use namespace 'auth' as a value.ts(2708)

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../services/user';
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore, // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      }
    });
  }
  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Sign up with email/password
  SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser
      .then((u: any) => u.sendEmailVerification())
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
      });
  }
  // Reset Forggot password
  ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
      .then(() => {
        window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
    return user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false ? true : false;
  }
  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then((res: any) => {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    });
  }
  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
```

/* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password,
sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth
provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
SetUserData(user: any) {
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument = this.afs.doc(
`users/${user.uid}`
);
const userData: User = {
uid: user.uid,
email: user.email,
displayName: user.displayName,
photoURL: user.photoURL,
emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
};
return userRef.set(userData, {
merge: true,
});
}
// Sign out
SignOut() {
return this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
localStorage.removeItem('user');
this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
});
}
}

i am getting this error Cannot use namespace 'auth' as a value.ts(2708)  please help me to fix it in angular 15